# Monitoring values and Write them

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a question.

I'm creating an app that use the bluetooth, I need to monitoring some values from  devices (one left and one right).

I have a trouble. At the moment I'm reading this data from devices and print them, but I should monitoring them so, do you believe that is better to write them in a file and then find a method to read what I have wrote? If the answer is Yes, how can I do to write them in a file?

This is what I print at the moment on the screen:

```
    return (
    <View>        
    <Text>{"Time:" + this.state.time}</Text>
    <Text>{"Acc:" + this.state.acc.join(" ")}</Text>
    <Text>{"Gyr:" + this.state.gyr.join(" ")}</Text>
    <Text>{"Mg:" + this.state.mg.join(" ")}</Text>
    <Text>{"Pressure:" + pressure}</Text>
    </View>
```

Comment: Monitoring means for while you will need to read and store and later you will start monitoring stored data ?

Comment: If you need to monitor, then you probably need to see changes from previous states and therefore store a history. It might be wise to store the data and let the frontend poll the datasource or implement pub/sub.

Comment: @SkidKadda Thank you, How can I store the data??

Comment: There are a lot of ways of accomplishing this. Maybe the easiest way for you is to see if you can implement a SaaS storage, like Firebase. A quick search on Youtube gave me this video you can watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwNATxfUsgI

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write this data there are plugins to do

[rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob)

[react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs)

With this you can **fetch data** and **read** and **write** storage.

Will that fulfil your requirements ?